# Website accesing information from database

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a database of something similar to the following:

```
SURNAME | NAME | YEAR OF BIRTH | SOMETHINGa | SOMETHINGb
```

I also have a webpage that needs to access this database. I want the page to display the entries by the  "YEAR OF BIRTH"-value (an `int`), or if there are several identical years by "SURNAME", in ascending order (using *CSS* to arrange them in tile-like fashion) and also use the other information ("SOMETHINGa/b") in each row. I also want to be able to keep adding to the database, and the webpage then re-ordering the displayed elements.
What is the best way of tackling this. I have basic knowledge of *Java/Javascipt*, so I thought about a Map or a 2D-array. Or is it worth learning *MySQL* for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encourage you to learn MySql or PostgreSql, both will work just fine for the database. Regarding the "keep adding to the database, and the webpage then re-ordering the displayed elements", a PHP/Javascript script called on LOAD will do just fine. As for the CSS design, thats up to your taste.

Good luck.